# Replace href with click event

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3

I have news articles that contain some anchor tags with href so I can not navigate in my ionic 3 application based on href. So what I have to do I must replace all href with click event and pass href value to that function as a parameter. So based on parameter I can push to some other page in my application.

I am getting an article like this.

```
Here it is some news article with <a href="tickcharts.php" ></a> and one more link like <a href="kalender.php" ></a> like this.
```

i have to achieve this

```
Here it is some news article with <a (click)="handlefunction(tickcharts.php)" ></a> and one more link like <a (click)="handlefunction(kalender.php)" ></a> like this.
```

so that I can easily navigate based on function parameter.

```
handlefunction(navpage){
if(navpage == 'tickcharts.php'){
// Navigate to tickcharts page in my app
}else if(navpage == 'kalender.php'){
// Navigate to kalender page
}
}
```

this news article comes from my mysql database.If its possible we can replace in a query but how?

Please help me to get out of this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with ionic, but I can give you an all-purpose JavaScript solution, if that helps:

```
window.addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (!event.target.hasAttribute('href')) return true;

    event.preventDefault();
    handlefunction(event.target.getAttribute('href'));
    return false;
});
```

This will capture all click events at the window level, and if the event originated on an element with a `href` attribute, it cancels the default action (i.e. browser navigation) and passes the `href` to your `handlefunction()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Router` which will help your problem

**HTML**

```
<a (click)="handlefunction(tickcharts.php)"
```

**TS**

```
constructor(private route: Router){

}

handlefunction(tickcharts){
if(navpage == 'tickcharts.php'){
 this.route.NavigateByUrl('PROVIDE URL');
}else if(navpage == 'kalender.php'){
this.route.NavigateByUrl('PROVIDE URL');
}
}
```

Comment: First i mus replace all href with click event then i can easily navigate.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```js
const handlefunction = href => console.log(href);

document
  .querySelectorAll('a')
  .forEach(link => {
    link.addEventListener('click',e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      handlefunction(e.target.getAttribute('href'));
    });
  });
```

```html
Here it is some news article with <a href="tickcharts.php">tickcharts</a> and one more link like <a href="kalender.php">kalender</a> like this.
```

Answer (score 0):

easiest way is this one:

```
handlefunction(){
window.open("path/to/your/tickcharts.php", "_blank"); //if you need it in new tab
window.location.open("path/to/your/tickcharts.php"); //in same tab
}
```

Comment: Actually the problem is my website contains these links which php server. But i am developing mobile applications for website using ionic 3 and implemented with nodejs so i can not navigate to path where it comes from. I must navigate with in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for every one from your inputs i got solution like this.

First i have filter data in my back end that i have replace all href with class.

```
var anchors = this.element.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName('a');
    if (length != 0) {
      for (var i = 0, length = anchors.length; i < length; i++) {
        var anchor = anchors[i];
        anchor.addEventListener('click', this.handlelinks.bind(this))
      };
    }
  }

  handlelinks(transition) {
     var navUrl =  transition.srcElement.classList[0];
     if(navUrl == 'tickcharts.php'){
      // go to tickcharts page
    } 
  }
```